# Why to access to a container by browser I have to set same host:container ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

as the question says.  Here it is my situation.
My project folder is:

```
PROJ    
|____docker-compose.yml  
|____servDir/  
        |____Dockerfile  
        |____server.py
```

In the docker-compose.yml:

```
service1:
    image: img1:v0.1
    container_name: cont1
    build: ./servDir/.
    ports:
      - "5001:5002"
```

server.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
PORT = 5001

@app.route("/greetings/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(PORT), debug=True)
```

When I run `docker-compose up` and go to `http://localhost:5001/greetings/`  I receive a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Instead, if I set *ports* as `5001:5001`, I'm able to receive the page content.

Why? Should I set them always equals, in order to reach the container by browser?

I thought that ports configuration was HOST:CONTAINER, and that browser would be a HOST sevice.

UPDATE:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR    /home/python/app/
COPY       . /home/python/app/
RUN        chmod a+x *.py

CMD        ["python", "./server.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is right : `HOST:CONTAINER`

Try to use this to expose it for your localhost and LAN :

```
service1:
    image: img1:v0.1
    container_name: cont1
    build: ./servDir/.
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5001:5002"
```

or this to only your localhost :

```
service1:
    image: img1:v0.1
    container_name: cont1
    build: ./servDir/.
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5001:5002"
```

Also, you wrote :

> When I run docker-compose up and go to http://localhost:6002/greetings/ I receive a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Looking at your docker compose you should access it like that instead:

http://localhost:6002 --> http://localhost:5001

Change `server.py` config :

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
PORT = 5002

@app.route("/greetings/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(PORT), debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed my **typo** and corrected it fast, but you were faster than me. I'm going to try your solution :D. thanx

Comment: Try to access http://127.0.0.1:5001/. If it doesn't work either, check your `hosts` file, be sure you have `127.0.0.1  localhost`.

Comment: I have ```127.0.0.1 localhost```in my hosts file

Comment: It's because you setted up the port `5001` in your `server.py` config BUT the container port you exposed is `5002`

Comment: I confirm. As I stated above: even if I switch ports in docker-compose:   
```
ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5002:5001"
```
it doesn't work. the only way it works is when the two values are the same, ```5001:5001```. Why?

Comment: Even if you set `docker-compose` to `ports: -5001:5002` and `server.py` to `PORT = 5002` it doesn't work on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ ?

Comment: I use docker every day (not with Python app) and it works like that... Check your python app settings, or can you provide your dockerfile config ?

Comment: Humm, there i dont see any way that it doesn't work because of docker... When you `docker-compose build` / `docker-compose up` your container does it run without returning error code ? Do you have python server logs ?

Comment: Can you try to start a Nginx container with similar port expose (0.0.0.0:5001:80) and see if it works? (also maybe it's a firewall issue)

Comment: I don't know how to do run a Nginx server :^), despite I'm able to run it's docker image as container. I never worked with Nginx. Any advices to configure it properly, or snippet?

Comment: Just run a standard Nginx image from the DockeHub and use default config, just expose contianer port 80 to your host port 5001 (`0.0.0.0:5001:80`) to see if your problem come from your python server container or form your host.

Comment: I just ran ```docker run --rm --name mynginx1 -p 2000:80 -d nginx``` and it works, I saw the home page at http://localhost:2000 ...
Maybe now is going because I allocated more resources to Docker yesterday. Now I'm going to do some tests on two servers communicating through their container ports and I'll update. Thank you [AppyGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10196815/appygg)